# Invertible State monad (and parsers)

Tags: parsing, haskell, state

Good day, ladies and gentlemen!

I'm constantly writing parsers and codecs. Implementing both parsers and printers seems to be massive code duplication. I wonder whether it is possible to invert a stateful computation, given it is isomorphic by nature.

It is possible to invert pure function composition (Control.Lens.Iso did that by defining a composition operator over isomorphisms). As it can be observed,

```
Iso bc cb . Iso ab ba = Iso (bc . ab) (ba . cb) -- from Lenses talk
invert (f . g) = (invert g) . (invert f)        -- pseudo-code
```

In other words, to invert a function composition one should compose inverted functions in the opposite order. So, given all primitive isomorphic pairs are defined, one can compose them to get more complicated pairs with no code duplication. Here is an example of pure bidirectional computation (Control.Lens is used, the [explanatory video](http://youtu.be/cefnmjtAolY?t=1h25m20s) can help you to get the general idea of Lenses, Folds and Traversals):

```
import Control.Lens

tick :: Num a => Iso' a a
tick = iso (+1) (subtract 1)   -- define an isomorphic pair

double :: Num a => Iso' a a
double = iso (+2) (subtract 2) -- and another one

threeTick :: Num a => Iso' a a
-- These are composed via simple function composition!
threeTick = double . tick

main :: IO ()
main = do
        print $ (4 :: Int)^.tick           -- => 5
        print $ (4 :: Int)^.from tick      -- => 3

        print $ (4 :: Int)^.threeTick      -- => 7, Composable
        print $ (4 :: Int)^.from threeTick -- => 1, YEAH
```

As you can see, I didn't need to supply the inverted version of `threeTick`; it is obtained by backward composition automatically!

Now, let's consider a simple parser.

```
data FOO = FOO Int Int deriving Show

parseFoo :: Parser FOO
parseFoo = FOO <$> decimal <* char ' '
               <*> decimal

parseFoo' :: Parser FOO
parseFoo' = do
    first <- decimal
    void $ char ' '
    second <- decimal
    return $ FOO first second


printFoo :: FOO -> BS.ByteString
printFoo (FOO a b) = BS.pack(show a) <>
                     BS.pack(" ")    <>
                     BS.pack(show b)


main :: IO ()
main = do
        print $ parseOnly parseFoo "10 11"  -- => Right (FOO 10 11)
        print $ parseOnly parseFoo' "10 11" -- => Right (FOO 10 11)

        print . printFoo $ FOO 10 11        -- => "10 11"
        print . parseOnly parseFoo . printFoo $ FOO 10 11 -- id
```

You can see that both versions of `parseFoo` are fairly declarative (thanks to parser combinators). Note the similarity between `parseFoo` and `printFoo`. Can I define isomorphisms over primitive parsers (`decimal` and `char`) and then just derive the printer (`printFoo :: FOO -> String`) automatically? Ideally, parser combinators will work as well.

I tried to redefine a monadic `>>=` operator in order to provide inverted semantics, but I've failed to do so. I feel that one could define inverted Kleisli composition operator (monadic function composition) similarly to composition inversion, but can one use it with ordinary monads?

```
f :: a -> m b,     inverse f :: b -> m a
g :: b -> m c,     inverse g :: c -> m b
inverse (f >=> g) = (inverse f) <=< (inverse g)
```

Why `inverse f` is of type `b -> m a` and not `m b -> a`? The answer is: monadic side effect is an attribute of an arrow, not that of a data type `b`. The state monad dualization is further discussed in the great Expert to Expert [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Expert-to-Expert-Brian-Beckman-and-Erik-Meijer-Inside-the-NET-Reactive-Framework-Rx/).

If the solution **does** exist, could you please supply a working example of `printFoo` derivation? By the way, here is an interesting [paper](http://www.informatik.uni-marburg.de/~rendel/rendel10invertible.pdf) that could help us find the solution.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think research into this sort of thing is what led to the early concepts of lenses which `Control.Lens` was birthed from. In particular, there are a lot of papers out there on bi-directional computing ("BX" sometimes) including one by Pierce that I keep citing for the definitions of the lens laws.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson I believe that strong enough theoretical background for bi-directional computing is already present. Is it of practical use, though? Had someone married `lens`es with Parsers (`MonadState` instances, more generally)? I think it's possible, but beyond my current abilities.

Comment: You may want to look at the `PU` parsers in the XML ecosystem (all the major XML ecosystems have them). They provide a mechanism for simultaneously describing printing and parsing and it's easy to supercharge them by writing some operations built from `Iso`s and `Prism`s. I personally still find them terrible to use, however, as they don't have the same structure that say an `Alternative` parser does.

Comment: s/gentlemen/ladies and gentlemen/

Answer (score 4):

You may be interested in digging in further into the `lens` package for the concept of a `Prism`.

A `Prism` can be used as a 'smart constructor' to build something (*e.g.* a pretty printed string) unconditionally, and match on it (*e.g.* `parse`).

You'd have to ignore the laws or treat the laws as holding only up to a quotient though, as the string you get out of pretty printing is very likely not *exactly* the string you parsed.

Comment: thank you. I'm trying to get the idea of prisms ([that](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/tel/lens-aeson-traversals-prisms) post is particularly useful). But anyway, you know `lens` ecosystem best, so could you please supply a 'hello world' example of `printFoo` derivation? As I can see, from [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.7.2/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html), every `Iso` is a `Prism`, but fail to use the former. If not, could you estimate the possibility of using Prisms and existing parsers in harmony (or shall I rewrite `Attoparsec` in order to do that).